# How to iterate through mixed type array and return the first integer

Tags: ruby

Given `x`:

```
x = ["stuff", "111", "other stuff", "more stuff"]
```

where the integer ("111" in this case) can be any positive integer, how do I get back the integer `111` to a variable and ideally delete it from the array?

Comment: In fact "111" is not an integer, if you do `"111".class` it return `String` ! `111` is a `Int`

Comment: You don't have any integer in the array. Do you mean a string that represents an integer? Do `"e2"` and/or `"3f"` qualifiy? What do you mean to "get back in integer to a variable"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was looking for a way to test the strings for an integer and return it.

Comment: What about "-10", "2.1" and "12A"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

```
x.find {|s| s =~ /^\d+$/}
# => "111"
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit differently:

```
x = ["stuff", "111", "other stuff",  "more stuff"]

found = x.select { |item| item == item.to_i.to_s } # (1)
p found
# => ["111"]

x -= found (2)
p x
# => ["stuff", "other stuff",  "more stuff"]
```

In `(1)` we're selecting all items, that we're trying to convert to `Integer`, and that convert that `Integer` to string again, so we can compare if the value is the same.

```
"111".to_i
# => 111
```

but

```
"hello".to_i
# => 0
```

So for non-integer strings, this alway is false.

Once you have your `found` items, you can remove them from `x` by `x -= found`.

Answer (score 2):

```
x.detect { |n| n =~ /^[0-9]+$/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to find string numbers, not integers, so you have to test for a string that is all numbers.

```
found = nil

for elem in x do
  if elem =~ /^[0-9]+$/
    found = elem
    break
  end
end

found
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this for one positive integer? or all positive integers? do want to remove the negative integers? will update answer if this isn't what you want.

Here is what I came up with:

```
x = ["stuff", "111", "other stuff",  "more stuff", "-12"]
int = x.grep(/^\d+$/).shift.to_s.to_i
i = x.index("#{int}")
x.delete_at(i)
```